# Default cell values when Inserting new row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

In Google Sheets, I would like to "Insert 1 row above/below" and have certain cells in this new row to have default values.

For example, when a new row is added, the cell in column C for this row will have the letter "N", column G will have a "Y", and column T will have a formula of "=sum(A2+B2)"  - of course the A2 and B2 will need to reflect the number of this new row.

What I have so far:

```
function addRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var range = source.getRange("'SAMPLE ROW'!A2:AJ2");
  range.copyValuesToRange(0, 4, 6, 4, 6);
}
```

The source.getRange is grabbing data from a hidden tab I am using.

How do I use the current Row in the copyValuestoRange section?

Answer (score 1):

To insert a new row you can use the function [insertRowBefore](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowBefore(Integer)) or [insertRowAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowAfter(Integer)), you just have to indicate the index (integer) of reference where the new row will be inserted.

```
sheet.insertRowBefore(2); //Here a new row will be inserted before the second row.
```

To insert values to the cells in the new row you can use the function setValue() from range.

```
sheet.getRange(2,3,1,1).setValue('N'); // this will insert the value N in the column C.
```

You can also use the a1Notaion to select a range. e.g. getRange('C2'). Here is the documentation about [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column) check it for more details.

I didn't understand your question "How do I use the current Row in the copyValuestoRange section?".

to get the values from a range, you have to call the range function getValues(). It will return a two dimensional array. then with the range function setValues() you can use that array to insert those values in the new range.

```
var values = source.getRange("'SAMPLE ROW'!A2:AJ2").getValues();
sheet.getRange('range_you_need').setValues(values);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Gerardo, thank you so much!  Where you have 'range_you_need' wouldn't this just be where I put my mouse and right clicked to add a row?  For example, if I am on row 67 and I click add 1 row above, how would I code in "get active row"?

Comment: Yes, in the example I gave if you add a row before row 2, the new row will be the row 2. But, if you use addRowAfter, then the new row will be row 3.  As I didn't know which function you were going to use (addRowBefore, addRowAfter), that's why I mentioned 'range_you_need'. With getActiveRow you will get the row that is selected in the UI. You can use setActiveRow() to programmatically set this value.