# Set column default value in Google Sheets

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a finance tracking worksheet that has a number of formulas for each row. What I'd like to add is have these formulas replicate whenever a new row is inserted (fill it with a "default value").

Sheet before adding the row:

[image: Before Adding Row]

Sheet after adding the row:

[image: After adding row]

I'd like some of these cells (B28 in this case) to contain a formula. for this row the formula is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C27), "", CONCATENATE(YEAR(C27), "-", MONTH(C27)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider an ArrayFormula. [Here's a place](https://www.labnol.org/internet/arrayformula-copy-formulas-in-entire-column/29711/) for getting detail. In your case, the big trick is knowing that you can run the formula through all of Column C using the notation something like C1:C.  Doing it this way is far more self documenting than burying it in a Google function and it's way more general.

Comment: This is a MUCH better way to do this - thanks Mark! Correct answer switched to this.

Answer (score 0):

Because the formula is the same for all rows, I added a function that just does the following:

```
function addRow() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B7:B').setValue('=IF(ISBLANK(C7), "", CONCATENATE(YEAR(C7), "-", MONTH(C7)))');
}
```

I set this function to run on a trigger whenever the sheet is edited. The row numbers increment themselves so not problem there either.

Used this SO question for help: [Default cell values when Inserting new row in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527549/default-cell-values-when-inserting-new-row-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in your **B** column and paste this into **B1** cell:

```
={"Date", ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C<>"", YEAR(C2:C)&"-"&MONTH(C2:C)))}
```